# How to configure Docker run as build step in teamcity?

Tags: docker, teamcity

I'm a beginner in docker, as well as in team city, I set up a pipeline for a build of a docker container and wanted to configure it to run after a successful build, I tried to use a step with a docker, but they advise using the command line with executable parameter and some way with docker socket, I crossed the Internet / YouTube did not see normal examples for starting a container after a build. I saw some examples of launching with agents, but again I did not understand anything in what was written, I looked for examples on YouTube, I also did not find it. Please give an example of running docker as a step in the pipeline on Linux.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my similar requirement on Jenkins by applying following..

Add a shell file (e.g. run.sh) in your project. In there have the docker run command that you will use from command line adding ***> /dev/null 2>&1 &*** at the end so that the process can be run in background and O/P streams to null.

```
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Then in your Jenkins (Teamcity) script add a *sh* step to run this file

```
steps {
    dir (whatever-dir-run.sh-is-in) {
      sh "JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe sh run.sh"
    }
}
```

Note: If JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE has an equivalent in Teamcity, use that.

Comment: I thought use it with Docker command, but recognize that better to use Command Line step and write code here just with: docker run image-name: tag, but anyway thanks!